# Batch File rename in folder and subfolders adding current dir as prefix to filenames

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I would like to have a windows batch file which gives prefix to all files on the same level where the batch file is and all files in the sub folders. The prefix would be the folder name which contains the batch file. I have a working code, but it only rename the docx files at the same folder level.

```
@echo off
for %%* in (.) do set CurrDirName1=%%~n*
FOR /f "delims=" %%F IN ('DIR /a-d /b *.docx')  DO (RENAME "%%F" "%CurrDirName1%-%%F")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...you are near. Add `/s` parameter to `dir` to include subdirectories and use `~nx` modifier for filename + extension for the `rename` command (`%%F` would be including the path and `rename` doesn't like that for the destination (needs `filename.extension` only)).

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%F IN ('DIR /s /a-d /b *.docx')  DO (RENAME "%%F" "%CurrDirName1%-%%~nxF")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
for %%* in (.) do set CurrDirName1=%%~n*
FOR /r "delims=" %%F IN ('DIR /a-d /b *.*')  DO (RENAME "%%F" "%CurrDirName1%-%%F")
```

Use this

Comment: I've tried with /r befor and now with your code but for some reason nothing is happening. The CMD says The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Could you clarify its working on your side and maybe Im doing something wrong?